# Parallels integration between iOS simulator and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, ios-simulator

How do I integrate an iPhone simulator on a Mac and Visual Studio 2015 that run in parallel on desktop 11?

I built simple request on xcode:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:49490/api/values/5", parameters: ["bar": "blabla"])
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
}
```

The `http://localhost:49490/api/values/5` is the url that was generated from Visual Studio. However, the url does not reach the server code

```
// GET api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

How can I create common networking between the 2 environments?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall or opening that port? The problem you are going to run into is that VS may choose random ports to host the server on, and you'll be chasing it around in XCode. It would be better to create a self-hosted solution or publish to a local IIS and test that way.

Comment: how to disable the firewall ?